# I wrote a function to merge two sorted arrays in C++, in code for merge sort, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone find the mistake in the code?

Tags: c++

```
//function to merge sorted arrays
void merge(int left[],int right[],int a[]){
     int lengthLeft=ARRAYSIZE(left);//ARRAYSIZE gets size of the array
     int lengthRight=ARRAYSIZE(right);
     int i=0,j=0,k=0;
     while(i<lengthLeft&&j<lengthRight){
         if(left[i]<=right[j]){
             a[k]=left[i];
             i++;
         }
         else{
             a[k]=right[j];
             j++;
         }
         k++;
     }
     while(i<lengthLeft){
         a[k]=left[i];
         k++;
         i++;
     }
     while(j<lengthRight){
         a[k]=right[j];
         k++;
         j++;
     }
}
```

The code apparently goes into an infinite loop. It shows program stopped working error. Logically, it seems perfectly alright, but I'm not getting the answer. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that expressions like this `ARRAYSIZE(left)` return incorrect sizes of arrays.

Thus `lengthLeft` and `lengthRight` get invalid values.

```
int lengthLeft=ARRAYSIZE(left);//ARRAYSIZE gets size of the array
int lengthRight=ARRAYSIZE(right);
```

As for other code in the function then it is correct.

You have to pass the arrays' lengths explicitly to the function.